# How to disable git gpg signing

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, sourcetree

I'm using git gpg signing. I want to disable it. I've set `.gitconfig`

```
[user]
    name = NAME
    email = EMAIL
    signingkey = KEY
...
[commit]
    gpgsign = false
```

My commits are still signing by default.

PS: I also disabled from Sourcetree `Repository/ Repository Settings/Security` tab. Both Sourcetree and terminal forces to use gpg.

Answer (score 123):

You can disable this by running `git config commit.gpgsign false` This sets the configuration locally instead of globally.

Putting this setting in .gitconfig worked for me with what you had, without the [user] configuration:

```
[commit]
    gpgsign = false
```

Comment: This one worked for me, `git config commit.gpgsign false`, thanks dude

Answer (score 98):

To temporarily disable GPG signing for the next commit:

```
git -c commit.gpgsign=false commit
```

Comment: can we create something like `git commit --disable-sign [...]` as a shortcut?

Answer (score 88):

To disable Git GPG signing for every repository on your computer

```
git config --global commit.gpgsign false
```

To disable Git GPG signing for a single repository

```
git config commit.gpgsign false
```

If you want to enable GPG signing again just replace `false` with `true`

Answer (score 63):

To unsign the last commit:

```
git commit --amend --no-gpg-sign
```

[**-no-gpg-sign**](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#git-commit---no-gpg-sign)

Countermand `commit.gpgSign` configuration variable that is set to force each and every commit to be signed.