# Git commit error: cannot spawn gpg.exe: No such file or directory

Tags: git, git-commit, gnupg, git-sign

This is what I am getting as output when I am trying to commit any file. I tried installing git again and watched some tutorials on youtube to get it started again but it didn't work. Still getting the same error:

```
error: cannot spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuPG\bin\gpg.exe: No such file or directory
error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object
```

Answer (score 8):

If you are using Git bash in Windows to generate the key instead of [GnuPG Win](https://gnupg.org/download/index.html), then you need to update the git config to point to the right location of gnupg. Run the following command in git bash with the correct location.

```bash
git config --global gpg.program /usr/bin/gpg
```

If you don't know the location run `which gpg` in git bash to obtain the location.

Comment: I was facing the exact same issue and your command saved the day! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Judging from the error message:

> ```
> error: cannot spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuPG\bin\gpg.exe: No such file or directory
> error: gpg failed to sign the data fatal: failed to write commit object
> ```

you have [git gpg signing](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Signing-Your-Work) turned on but no [GnuPG](https://gnupg.org/software/index.html) installed. Either install it or turn off commit gpg signing. You can disable commit signing using [`--no-gpg-sign`](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#Documentation/git-commit.txt---no-gpg-sign) flag on a particular commit command:

```
git commit --no-gpg-sign
```

or [disable it permanently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39274739/how-to-disable-git-gpg-signing) by modyfing your global `.gitconfig`:

```
git config --global commit.gpgsign false
```

Answer (score 2):

I also faced this issue and was able to fix it by removing quotes for the gpg.exe program line in .gitconfig file.

.gitconfig file before update =>

[gpg]
program = 'C:\Users\TEST\AppData\Local\GnuPG\bin\gpg.exe'

.gitconfig file after update =>

[gpg]
program = C:\Users\TEST\AppData\Local\GnuPG\bin\gpg.exe